# Using a Model Instance in Ember Component Integration Tests

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to do an integration test for an Ember component that requires a model as input. I have mock data, but I cannot pass it into the component directly because the model includes computed properties and other customizations that EmberData normally handles under the hood. However, I cannot figure out how to inject the store into the test to convert my mock data into an Ember model. I've tried a few different approaches, none of which work:

```
Ember.inject.service('store');
this.get('store')

var store = this.container.lookup('service:store');

Ember.getOwner(this).lookup("service:store");
```

None of these actually work. I'm using Ember v2.9.1. The code for my integration test is below.

```
import { moduleForComponent, test } from 'ember-qunit';
import hbs from 'htmlbars-inline-precompile';

moduleForComponent('host-pod', 'Integration | Component | host-pod', {
  integration: true
});

test('it renders', function(assert) {

  ... code to get store ...

  this.set('mockModel', store.normalize('model', mockModel));
  this.render(hbs`{{component model=mockModel show='all' mode='grouped'}}`);

  assert.equal(this.$().length, 1);
});


var mockModel = { ... }
```